# Complex mappings between Domain Model and Data Model – do we risk losing the tight coupling?

Tags: domain-driven-design

From [DDD: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) (pg. 159/160):

> When database schema is being created specificaly as a store for the objects, it is worth accepting
>   some model limitations in order to keep the mapping very simple
>
> ...
>
> This does entail some sacrifice in the richness of the object model, and sometimes compromises have
>   to be made in the database design (such as selective denormalization), but to do otherwise is to
>   risk losing the tight coupling of model and implementation.
>
> ...
>
> But it is crucial that the mappings be transparent, easily understandable by inspecting the code or
>   reading entries in the mapping tool.
>
> ...
>
> When database is being viewed as an object store, don't let the data model and the object model
>   diverge far, regardless of the powers of the mapping tools. Sacrifice some richness of object
>   relationships to keep close to the relational model.

I do understand that with simpler mappings the *Data Mappers* will be easier to maintain, less buggy etc, but I don't understand why we could also risk losing the tight coupling between a *Domain Model* and *DM's implementation* by making mappings between *DM* and *Data Model* complex.

Namely, when creating a *DM*, we should try to be oblivious of how non-domain layers will be implemented and what techologies they will use. And since *Data Mappers* resides within *DAL* ( thus outside the *Domain layer* ), how then could the complexity of a mapping between *DM* and *Data Model* ( and thus the complexity of *Data Mappers* ) have any impact on the coupling between *DM* and *DM's implementation*?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote is actually:

> but to do otherwise is to risk losing the tight coupling of model and implementation

It is talking about the coupling of the *conceptual* model and its implementation (in code). This is not a discussion about data mappers and mapping data to the implemented model, but about how you can lose fidelity to the conceptual model when implementing it - in particular when you need to consider a database or other implementation details.

Comment: I did ask why by having complex mappings we would risk losing tight coupling between Domain Model ( ie conceptual model ) and Domain Model's implementation

Comment: @user437291 - Because you would need to make compromised when doing such mappings between the data model and the implemented model that would drive the implemented model away from the conceptual model.

Comment: But why would such compromises be needed? As noted in my question, as far as I understand it, DDD should be oblivious to how other layers ( including DAL ) are implemented

Comment: @user437291 - _should_. But we live in the _real world_, where sometimes, the domain model is such that it would cause a very inefficient way to use a database (causing unacceptable performance issues). To resolve such inefficiencies, you would have to compromise (use the database in an efficient manner, compromising the domain model). This is just one example of the trade-offs that sometimes impact the ideal domain model.

Comment: uhm, now I'm confused since from the beginning of the book author was emphasizing that the key to succesfull Domain Model is focusing only on the domain model ( and thus be oblivious to how other layers are implemented ). Anyways, doesn't this mean that we should also make some compromises in domain model when using some other ( ie non-DAL ) infrastructure services?

Comment: @user437291 - Sure. But the point is to **try** to minimize these as much as possible and try to remain as true as possible to the conceptual model.

Comment: I must confess by learning that compromises will have to be made that DDD just got a bit more complicated. Anyways, much appreciated